# JQuery. How to select some cells at each row?

Tags: jquery, html-table, each

I'm a bit stuck trying to resolve this problem.
I need get content of a few cells, and after this do update inner text of this cells

For example, I need to get values of cells with 
class = 2 and class = 4
in each row, and after this, update their inner text

I tried to do it by this code:

```
$(element).each(function ()
{
   // code code code
});
```

But isn't really something, what i need, because this code just get each element at each row, but i need get a few elements at each row at one time

It's should be lookin something like :

1. get row.
2. get elements with class = 1 and class = 2 at current row
3. send their content to script
4. update content of cells
5. get next row
6. etc

Here is example table:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="1"> Cell One </td>
        <td class="2"> Cell Two </td>
        <td class="3"> Cell Three </td>
        <td class="4"> Cell Four </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="1"> Also one Cell One </td>
        <td class="2"> Also one Cell Two </td>
        <td class="3"> Also one Cell Three </td>
        <td class="4"> Also one Cell Four </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**

> And also. .

**

> I need send Ajax Query, for each row in table, with inner text of 2
>   cells of current row ajax.php?id=column1&val=column2

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like

Also I think what you are trying is whether the current td has class 1 or 2 for that you can use [.hasClass()](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/)

```
$('table').find('tr').each(function(){
    var $tr = $(this);
    $tr.find('.1, .2').html(function(idx, html){
        var $td = $(this);

        if($td.hasClass('1')){
            return html + ' class-1';
        } else if($td.hasClass('2')){
            return html + ' class-2';
        }

        return html + ' modified'
    })
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/aBTP2/)

Answer (score 1):

The following will give you a set of all `class="1"` and `class="2"` in one go:

```
$('tr .1, tr .2')
```

You may then do something like this:

```
$('tr .1, tr .2').each(function() {
    if($(this).is('.1')) {
       // class="1" stuff
    } else {
       // class="2" stuff
    }
});
```

If you prefer to do the iteration by row, you could just select the rows, `$('tr')`, and then find the children of interest inside the iteration:

```
$('tr').each(function() {
    var cols = $('.1, .2', this);
    // do something with cols
});
```

There are many ways forward; the best solution would depend on the details of what you're trying to acheive.

Comment: It's lookin like something what can help. Really big thanks :3

Comment: I wrote at the topic head, what i try to acheive